# Is there a more specialized word for "expedite" for the case where the thing was not making any progress at all to begin with?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

For a process which isn't moving quickly enough, one can do things to expedite it. But for something which is a sluggish bottleneck and is not making any progress whatsoever, is there a more specialized word for "expediting" it?

Answer (score 6):

[kickstart](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/kick-start) *- to make something improve or become more active after it has stopped or slowed down.*

Another definition that might fit OP's context better: [To kick-start a process that has stopped working or progressing is to take a course of action that will quickly start it going again.](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-cobuild/kick-start)

Comment: Or [jumpstart](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jump-start) - impart fresh energy to, start/restart rapidly or forcefully

Answer (score 3):

The phrase *breaking a log-jam* is sometimes used.

Also, if the reason for the lack of progress is bureaucracy, *cutting through red tape*.

Answer (score 1):

*[Invigorate](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/invigorate#Verb)* (“To heighten or intensify”, “To give life or energy to”) is a possibility. Also  *[reinvigorate](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/reinvigorate)* (“To give new life, energy or strength to someone or something; to revitalize”).  Note, *[revitalize](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/revitalize#Verb)* means  “To give new life, energy, activity or success to something”.

Also consider *[reanimate](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/reanimate#Verb)* (“To animate anew; to restore to animation or life; to infuse new life, vigor, spirit, or courage into; to revive; to reinvigorate; as, to reanimate a drowned person; to reanimate disheartened troops; to reanimate languid spirits”), *[stir up](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/stir_up)* (“arouse or excite passion or action”), *[instigate](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/instigate#Verb)* and its synonyms *encourage, impel, incite, provoke, spur, stimulate, tempt, urge*, and *[reawaken](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/reawaken)* (“To reactivate or reanimate”).

Phrases *[light a fire under](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/light+a+fire+under)*, *[get the ball rolling](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+the+ball+rolling)*, and  *[jumpstart](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/jumpstart)* (“start or re-start vigorously”) also are relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Enlivened.

Reborn.

Was moribund, but ...
The till now moribund / bogged down project was ...

Given a new breath of life ...

I'd say that jwpat7's "revitalised" was a pretty good choice.

A new start

Getting things moving.

Taking the handbrake off.

Introduced a new broom / A new broom.
Cleared the temple (reference to Christ & merchants in temple)

Changed up two gears

A breath of fresh air

A new hand at the helm

A long overdue ...